# Get multiple arrays of similar objects from an array in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm

I have an array of this type of objects:

```
{id: 543, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Foo', age: 32}
```

I would like to filter out those objects in an array which share the same value for `firstName` AND `age` properties. So the result would be multiple arrays with elements with same value of `age` AND `firstName`. Something like this:

```
[{id: 543, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Foo', age: 32},
{id: 123, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Bar', age: 32},
{id: 432, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Baz', age: 32}]

[{id: 989, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Smith', age: 67},
{id: 876, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Miller', age: 67},
{id: 334, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Stone', age: 67}]
```

How would you solve this in a simple and elegant way? (can be in ES6)

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please update your question and include the source code where you have made an attempt to get expected output. This isn't a free writing service so it is recommended you show/include your attempt(s). thank you.

Comment: Filter is what you're looking for: [Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce()` and `Object.values()` methods to return array of arrays.

```js
const data = [
  {id: 543, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Foo', age: 32},
  {id: 123, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Bar', age: 32},
  {id: 432, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Baz', age: 32},
  {id: 989, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Smith', age: 67},
  {id: 876, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Miller', age: 67},
  {id: 334, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Stone', age: 67}
]

const result = Object.values(data.reduce(function(r, e) {
  const key = `${e.firstName}|${e.age}`;
  if(!r[key]) r[key] = [e];
  else r[key].push(e)
  return r;
}, {}))

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 1):

I would group them by property using nested objects. (a flat object using concatenated keys would work just as fine, but i don't like gluing strings together).

After grouping them, flatten them into a single array.

```
var data = [
  {id: 543, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Foo', age: 32},
  {id: 123, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Bar', age: 32},
  {id: 432, firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Baz', age: 32},
  {id: 989, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Smith', age: 67},
  {id: 876, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Miller', age: 67},
  {id: 334, firstName: 'George', lastName: 'Stone', age: 67}
]

function flatten (obj, flat) {
   return Object.keys (obj).reduce ((arr, key) => arr.concat (!Array.isArray (obj [key])?flatten (obj [key]):[obj[key]]), [])
}

function groupBy (keys, arr) {
   return arr.reduce (function (group, item) {
        let node, val;
        for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
            val = item [keys[i]]
            if (i == keys.length - 1) node [val] = node [val] || []
            else node = node && (node [val] = node [val] || {}) || (group [val] = group [val] || {})
        }

        node[val].push (item);
        return group;
   }, {})
}

console.log (flatten (groupBy (["firstName", "age"], data)))
```